# Chaging background color on hover using foreach

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I am using this code (smarty php template code)

```
{foreach $rewards as $reward}
                            <div id="reward" data-id="{$reward['id']}">
                                <div class="reward_data{$reward['id']}">
                                    <b>{strtoupper($reward['title'])}:</b><br/>
                                    {html_entity_decode($reward['description'])}
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <b>Estimated Delivery:</b> {$reward['estimated_delivery_date']}
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Select This Project</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                        {/foreach}
```

and in jquery i am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reward').hover(function () {
        var reward_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("background-color", "#2bde73");
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("padding", "10px");
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("border-radius", "10px");
    }, function () {
        var reward_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    });
});
```

On hover ist result from foreach the background color is changed but on 2nd and above results there is effect of on hover. Please help me related this
I am thankful to you

Comment: Looks like you have mulitple elements with the same ID, that might be a problme. Also, why not using plain ol' CSS?

Comment: i m getting different ids here var reward_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

Comment: No you're not, #reward is called multiple times

Comment: Refer @Kevin Nagurski answer it is simple and straight forward

Answer (score 1):

For simply changing the background color on hover, CSS is the tool you need. First of all, you need to use `class` instead of `id` as ids should be unique.

So

```
<div id="reward" data-id="{$reward['id']}">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="reward" data-id="{$reward['id']}">
```

Then create a new CSS rule as follows

```
.reward:hover .reward-data {
    background-color: #2bde73;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

No need for JS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)

If you know that an ID needs to be unique, you'll see that this won't work: you have the ID "reward" multiple times.

A solution could be that you change the ID to a class, and change the hash to a dot in your jquery.

Comment: working now i had changed #reward to .reward and .reward-data to #reward-data

Answer (score 0):

change your id to class:

```
{foreach $rewards as $reward}
                            <div class="reward" data-id="{$reward['id']}">
                                <div class="reward_data{$reward['id']}">
                                    <b>{strtoupper($reward['title'])}:</b><br/>
                                    {html_entity_decode($reward['description'])}
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <b>Estimated Delivery:</b> {$reward['estimated_delivery_date']}
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger">Select This Project</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                        {/foreach}
```

And jquery as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.reward').hover(function () {
        var reward_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("background-color", "#2bde73");
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("padding", "10px");
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("border-radius", "10px");
    }, function () {
        var reward_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.reward_data' + reward_id).css("background-color", "#ffffff");
    });
});
```